# vessels and dipping

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping

1. How many times does one *halachically* have to dip a vessel into a *mikveh*?
2. Is one allowed to wet his hand in the מקוה prior to dipping as opposed to letting go of the vessel so that the water can reach every part of it. Where *halachic* source for this?

Comment: When one does teivilah they should not hold the utensil tightly so water reaches everywhere,or dip ones hand into the water first (Rama 120:2 with Nosei Keilim ) one dipping is halachicly mandated three times is a minhag

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "how many times does one have to dip"? *Mei'ikar hadin*? To satisfy a *minhag*? (Note that the minhag to dip three times may not be universal). 2. Consider generalizing your final sentence, as we can't know for sure what that individual was thinking. (This might be why the question was put on hold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should hold it loosely or dip his hand in mikva water first in order that the whole kli gets toiveled.

source: Shulchan Aruch 120:3 :

> צריך שיהא הכלי רפוי בידו בשעת טבילה שאם מהדקו בידו הוי חציצה ואם לחלח ידו במים‏ תחלה אין לחוש. (ודוקא שלחלח ידיו במי מקוה אבל לא במים תלושים) (משמע ממרדכי פרק השוכר)‏:‏

One dipping is halachicly mandated while three times is a minhag.

Comment: Is three really a "minhag"? Or is it just something some people do for no reason? Has anyone of note claimed the custom is worthwhile/authoritative/binding?

Comment: Sefer Hamanig I believe

Comment: Menachem what halachic source specifies that one dips a vessel in a mikvah only once?