Why don't we say Likboa Mezuzos?
When putting up a mezuzah, we say the blessing Baruch....Asher Kideshanu...Likboa Mezuzah.
This blessing is said whether putting up one mezuzah or putting up multiple.
Why don't we say likboa Mezuzos when putting up multiple Mezuzos?
For example when toiveling keilim we say al tvilas keli for singular utensils but we say keilim for multiple vessels.

Can you name any other example like that?

@DoubleAA https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136680/can-a-woman-take-a-spoon-with-her-to-the-mikvah#comment455196_136690

@Heshy yes but that's combining multiple mitzvot, the better analogy may be להכניסם  but anyway the exception here is clearly not mezuza

שבט הלוי - חלק ו סימן קס
